# Critique my proof of: Suppose A, B, and C are sets. Then $A \cap (B \setminus C) = (A \cap B) \setminus C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I want to thank you guys a lot for the help. I feel like I'm improving a lot in mathematical proof because of your willingness to critique my proofs.

**Theorem.** *Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets. Then $A \cap (B \setminus C) = (A \cap B) \setminus C.$*

*Proof.* Let $x$ be an arbitrary element and $x \in A \cap (B \setminus C)$. It follows that $x \in A \cap (B \setminus C)$ $$\text iff \ x \in A \land x \in B \setminus C$$ $$ \text iff \ x \in A \land x \in B \land x \not\in C $$ $$\text iff \ x \in (A \cap B) \setminus C$$
Thus, $\forall x(x \in A \cap (B \setminus C) \iff x \in (A \cap B) \setminus C). \\ \therefore A \cap (B \setminus C) =(A \cap B) \setminus C.$

Comment: You can use \text to format text within dollar signs so you can get $\text{iff}$. And your proof looks good.

Comment: @John Douma Thanks! I'm new to LaTex too, so any help with that is much appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.

According to the properties and definitions involved, we can conclude that

\begin{align*}
A\cap(B\backslash C) & = A\cap (B\cap C^{c})\\\\
& = (A\cap B)\cap C^{c}\\\\
& = (A\cap B)\backslash C
\end{align*}

and we are done.

As to your proof, it sounds good.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks! What exactly is $C^{c}$, though?

Comment: It means the complement of $C$. Let $U$ be the universe of discourse. Then we have:
$$X^{c} = \{x\in U \mid x\not\in X\}$$